# How to type the iterator of a for loop as numeric string?

Tags: typescript, for-loop, types, iterator, number-formatting

Even though I have declare the type for the iterator `i` as `NumericalString`, TypeScript still throws this error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'type'.deno-ts(2345)

I understand that because when `test(i)` is called, there is no way for the IDE to know that `i` is indeed a numerical string. So how to overcome this? I don't want to convert it to number manually.

```
type NumericalString = `${number}` | number

function test (i: NumericalString) {
    console.log(i, typeof i)
}

for (const i in ['a', 'b', 'c']) {
    test(i) 
}
```

Note: I need the loop to be `for...in`, not `for...of`. In the actual data, I have a pair of arrays, say `arr1 = ['John', 'Mary', 'Tom']; arr2 = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']`. So that I can do `for (i in arr1) {console.log(arr2[i])}`

Comment: IMHO your trying to resolve a runtime casting problem with static typing solution.
here your trying to use a string value as `${number}` value (you noted it btw). the right method is iterate through a NumericalString array not a string array. but in this case TS wil complain about the three values you put in the array. Type system is not a way to sanitize data, that's a very wrong way to use it and it will lead you to many wrong solution. if you don't trust your data (and that's a resonable point) so properly sanitize your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Now that's not a TypeScript typing problem anymore. `for...in` always returns the key as a `string`. Obviously, a `string` is neither assignable to `number` nor `"${number}"`.
A possible workaround is using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) manually, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) all keys to a `number` and iterate over the values using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
type NumericalString = `${number}` | number;

function test(i: NumericalString) {
  console.log(i, typeof i);
}

for (const i of Object.keys(["a", "b", "c"]).map(Number)) {
  test(i);
}
```

**Original Answer**

The problem here is that `for...in` loops over the keys. You want to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead to loop over the values of e. g. `["1", "2", "3"]`. However, I'm not sure about why you would want to pass an item of `['a', 'b', 'c']` (an array that clearly consists of `string`s) to a function with a parameter of type `NumerialString`.

```
type NumericalString = `${number}` | number;

function test(i: NumericalString) {
  console.log(i, typeof i);
}

const items: NumericalString[] = ["1", "2", "2"];

for (const i of items) {
  test(i);
}
```